# passing "this" in C# generic doesnt work without casting

Tags: c#

I tried googling and stackoverflow but couldnt find answer to my specific problem (and even limited knoweldge of generics)

So I posted here in hope for the answer.

Here is my class

```
public abstract class AThemeableControl<TManager, TControl>
    where TManager:AManagerTheme<TManager, TControl>
    where TControl:AThemeableControl<TManager, TControl>
{
    public abstract void UpdateTheme(TManager managerTheme);
}
```

Here is the manager class

```
public abstract class AManagerTheme<TManager, TControl>
    where TManager:AManagerTheme<TManager, TControl>
    where TControl:AThemeableControl<TManager, TControl>
{
    public TControl[] ThemableControls;

    virtual public void ApplyTheme()
    {
        for (int i = ThemableControls.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            ThemableControls[i].UpdateTheme(this); //ERROR HERE           
        }           
    }
}
```

So I'm able to solve this error by typecasting

```
ThemableControls[i].UpdateTheme((TManager) this);
```

But I want to know the solution without typecasting which I'm hopeful is possible.

Comment: `UpdateTheme` takes a `TManager`. Your're trying to call `UpdateTheme(this)` inside `AManagerTheme<TManager, TControl>`. However, `UpdateTheme` takes a `TManager`, not an `AManagerTheme<TManager, TControl>`. That's where your error comes from. I can't suggest a solution from the context you've given - we don't know what you're trying to achieve, other than you're trying to write code which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Derive `AManagerTheme<TManager, TControl>` from TManager.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, `ApplyTheme` is a member of `AManagerTheme`, which has no base class, so this is only known to be an instance of `AManagerTheme`, and not of any other class.  The `UpdateTheme` method takes an instance of `TManager` as a parameter.  I can see where the cast is needed.  What are your objections to the cast?

Comment: I dont have any objections to the cast, im able to use it like this with concrete classes. 
But i wanted to learn if casting is avoidable or not.

Comment: I'm guessing you are not actually solving the error by casting, I think you're just getting rid of the compiler error.

Comment: @Fildor: I don't think "use interfaces" is terribly helpful here. This is really a question of types that have a sort of symbiotic relationship, and how that can be expressed in a type-safe way in C# generics - and it just doesn't work, unfortunately. If you have a concrete suggestion for what the code would look like using interfaces, it would be worth adding that as an answer - but on its own, "use interfaces" is not helpful IMO.

Comment: reason i dont want interface because i want concrete themeControl to know the concrete theme. this way i can use the same theme setup for different projects where controls have to know the actual theme manager and its methods as there is no theming standard where im using C# because each implementation may provide different method to controls

Comment: @Max ok, that's a _very_ special set of requirements then ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't remove the cast, because it would be unsafe to do so. Here's an example where the cast throws:

```
using System;

public abstract class AManagerTheme<TManager, TControl>
    where TManager : AManagerTheme<TManager, TControl>
    where TControl : AThemeableControl<TManager, TControl>
{
    public TControl[] ThemableControls;

    public virtual void ApplyTheme()
    {
        for (int i = ThemableControls.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            ThemableControls[i].UpdateTheme((TManager) this);
        }           
    }
}

public abstract class AThemeableControl<TManager, TControl>
    where TManager : AManagerTheme<TManager, TControl>
    where TControl : AThemeableControl<TManager, TControl>
{
    // Empty implementation; irrelevant for the question.
    public void UpdateTheme(TManager managerTheme) {}
}

public class NormalTheme : AManagerTheme<NormalTheme, NormalControl>
{
}

public class NormalControl : AThemeableControl<NormalTheme, NormalControl>
{
}

public class EvilTheme : AManagerTheme<NormalTheme, NormalControl>
{
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var theme = new EvilTheme
        {
            ThemableControls = new[] { new NormalControl() }
        };
        theme.ApplyTheme();
    }
}
```

This is what you'd *like* to prevent:

```
public class EvilTheme : AManagerTheme<NormalTheme, NormalControl>
```

... but you can't express that with C# generics. (I faced the same sort of thing in an earlier version of Protocol Buffers, where each "message" type had a corresponding "builder" type.) The C# type system just isn't rich enough to express this.

You might want to check for validity within the abstract class constructor, so that at least you know the cast will work later. But you can't avoid either casting *or* using a different `TManager` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Jon, if i understand correctly, there is no way i can avoid typecasting , right? (making it safe is another problem though)

Comment: @Max: Not while you want to assume that the execution-time type of any `AManagerTheme<TManager, TControl>` instance is the same type as the corresponding `TManager` type. That's just something that can't be expressed in C#, so the cast is a way of saying "I know better than you, please just check it for me at execution time"

Comment: Thanks Jon, i understand now :)

Comment: @Max As long as you don't inherit from the class and want to access a specific property like from "NormalTheme" you can just change the method to: `public void UpdateTheme(AManagerTheme<TManager, TControl> managerTheme)`.

Comment: @FelixK.: My experience with situations like this is that the concrete classes very often *do* have methods/properties they want to use from each other. It's possible that this is not the case here, but...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes i did use scenarios like the one above multiple times. I think that the JIT might optimize the cast anyway when both types are equal or no casting is required, so there should be no impact unless you specify a type which will throw an error anyway.